Altium ' Failed to add class member ' Error
I have a simple buck converter made from TL494.
I saved my project and closed it. I opened it and tried to add a component. Whatever I add to the schematic and import changes to PCB, I have 2 errors which are:

Failed to add class member

Unknown Pin


Before I closed the project everything was fine, although I copied the same component which was imported to pcb successfully is not being imported now .
I tried  Tools > Update from PCB libraries, but it didn't work.
I tried Force Annotate All Schematic, I only solved the ' Unknown pins' error. Failed to to add class member error remains. How can ı solve this issue?

Source: My project, ECO table

Source: My project, when I click on 'Update from pcb library'

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

The "Unknown Pin" error is a result of the footprint pad designator not matching the schematic symbol pin designator. Open the footprint for the capacitor you're trying to add. I suspect the pad designators are currently set to something like "N" and "P" (for a polarized capacitor, these designate the "Negative" and "Positive" pads). If it is a polarized capacitor, use the correct schematic symbol with "N" and "P" pin designators. If it is a non-polarized capacitor, make sure you select a footprint with "1" and "2" pad designators.
